# Why does the creation of the view take so long in snowflake

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

Usually creating a view doesn't take much time, but unfortunately I create a view that takes me over 30 minutes.

snowflake view

And I wonder what can cause this?

I expect that I understand the creation of view in snowflake !

```sql
with

    phone_without_outlier as (
        (

            with
                phone__outlier as (
                    (


                        with
                            outliers__view as (
                                select input::varchar as phone
                                from relation_1
                                where is_outlier = true and feed_id = 'hi'
                                union
                                select phone::varchar as phone
                                from relation_2
                                where allow = true and feed_id = 'hi'
                            )

                        select *
                        from outliers__view


                    )
                ),
                phone_outlier__flattened as (
                    select
                        id,
                        phone_normalized,
                        phone_toll_free_normalized,
                        companies.value::varchar as phone_or_other

                    from relation_3,
                        lateral flatten(input => phones) companies
                ),
                phone__without_outlier as (
                    select
                        id,
                        iff(
                            phone_or_other = phone_normalized, phone_or_other, null
                        ) as phone_normalized,
                        iff(
                            phone_or_other = phone_toll_free_normalized,
                            phone_or_other,
                            null
                        ) as phone_toll_free_normalized,
                        iff(
                            phone_or_other != phone_normalized
                            and phone_or_other != phone_toll_free_normalized,
                            phone_or_other,
                            null
                        ) as other_phone_normalized
                    from phone_outlier__flattened
                    where coalesce(trim(phone_or_other), '') != '' and phone_or_other not in (select distinct phone from phone__outlier)
                ),
                phone_without_outlier__grouped as (
                    select
                        id,
                        array_compact(array_agg(distinct phone_normalized))[0]::varchar
                        as phone_normalized,
                        array_compact(array_agg(distinct phone_toll_free_normalized))[
                            0
                        ]::varchar as phone_toll_free_normalized,
                        joel_dbt.array_distinct_objects(
                            array_compact(
                                array_unique_agg(
                                    iff(
                                        coalesce(trim(other_phone_normalized), '')
                                        != '',
                                        object_construct_keep_null(
                                            'type',
                                            null,
                                            'carrier',
                                            null,
                                            'status',
                                            null,
                                            'status_last_verification_date',
                                            null,
                                            'score',

                                            (
                                                iff(
                                                    other_phone_normalized is not null,
                                                    1,
                                                    0
                                                ) + iff(
                                                    other_phone_normalized like '%+%',
                                                    1,
                                                    0
                                                )
                                            )
                                            / 2,
                                            'priority',
                                            null,
                                            'phone',
                                            other_phone_normalized,
                                            'ddi',
                                            null,
                                            'dnc',
                                            false

                                        ),
                                        null
                                    )
                                )
                            ),
                            'phone',
                            true
                        ) as other_phone_normalized_list
                    from phone__without_outlier
                    group by id
                )

            select *
            from phone_without_outlier__grouped
        )
    )

select
    id,
    phone_normalized,
    phone_toll_free_normalized,
    other_phone_normalized_list,
    (
        iff(phone_normalized is not null, 1, 0)
        + iff(phone_normalized like '%+%', 1, 0)
    ) / 2 as company_phone_score,
    (
        iff(phone_toll_free_normalized is not null, 1, 0)
        + iff(phone_toll_free_normalized like '%+%', 1, 0)
    ) / 2 as company_phone_toll_free_score,
    joel_dbt.array_distinct_objects(
        joel_dbt.array_cat_distinct(
            array_cat(

                array_construct_compact(
                    iff(
                        coalesce(trim(phone_normalized), '')
                        != '',
                        object_construct_keep_null(
                            'type',
                            null,
                            'carrier',
                            null,
                            'status',
                            null,
                            'status_last_verification_date',
                            null,
                            'score',
                            company_phone_score,
                            'priority',
                            null,
                            'phone',
                            phone_normalized,
                            'ddi',
                            null,
                            'dnc',
                            false

                        ),
                        null
                    )
                ),

                array_construct_compact(
                    iff(
                        coalesce(
                            trim(phone_toll_free_normalized), ''
                        )
                        != '',
                        object_construct_keep_null(
                            'type',
                            null,
                            'carrier',
                            null,
                            'status',
                            null,
                            'status_last_verification_date',
                            null,
                            'score',
                            company_phone_toll_free_score,
                            'priority',
                            null,
                            'phone',
                            phone_toll_free_normalized,
                            'ddi',
                            null,
                            'dnc',
                            false

                        ),
                        null
                    )
                )

            ),
            other_phone_normalized_list
        ),
        'phone',
        true
    ) as phones
from relation_4
left join phone_without_outlier using (id)
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the view creation code

Comment: You need to simplify this more into something small and reproducible. Try cutting out joins, fields, etc., one-by-one until the view builds quickly, then add things back until it's slow again to isolate the issue. We don't know enough about your data to help you.

Answer (score 0):

to save someone else time, the problem was that dbt was having trouble compiling the code because there was a problem using nested macros. you have to be careful about the depth of use of the macro.

that caused Ctes within Ctes